# Redirecting own domain to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, hosting, shinyapps

I'd like to use my own domain names for apps hosted at shinyapps.io. I can't afford the Professional option.
I have, say, the domain theorymaker.info registered elsewhere, can I redirect it to shinyapps so that also  theorymaker.info?query=querystring will work seamlessly and invisibly?